# IIS log giving 500 error with no description in event viewer

Tags: application-pool, integrated-pipeline-mode, applicationpoolidentity, iis-logs

I have my application developed in hybrid technology (asp classic + asp.net). Initially it was hosted on IIS with "Classic" Pipeline mode. I Upgraded Application Pool Pipeline mode from "Classic" to "Integrated" after that unexpected 500 errors started logging in IIS log with no descirption.

I did a lot of research and found that it happens only then when pool recycles.

Can anyone please help me to get this issue resolved? I am stuck at this point.

Comment: Please kindly check full error message on the server first as 500 internal server error is generic issue. It is hard to determine your problem

Comment: I tried to get full error message but there is nothing except this 500 internal server error with exception code 0 64. I googled about this exception code it gave "Network name is no longer available". One thing I doubt is that may be this issue is occurred on request received by the IIS server during the pool recycling.

Comment: Have you login to the server to check it? If you are not logged in to the server, you wont know the full error message